# Autoform with Meteor React and Simple-Schema

Tags: meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, meteor-react, meteor-1.4

Is there any possibility to make [meteor-autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) work with [meteor-collection2-core](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core) and [react-meteor](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-meteor)?

**MWE**

Preferably I would like to have something like this.

*./imports/api/Books.js*

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
const Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");
Books.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 200
    },
        author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author"
    },
}));
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('allBooks', function () {
        return Books.find({}, );
    });
};
export default Books;
```

*./imports/client/NewBooks.js*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { quickForm } from 'meteor-autoform';
import Books from '../api/Books';
class NewBooks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <quickForm
            collection={Books}
            id="insertBookForm"
            type="insert">
        </quickForm>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('allBooks');
  return {
    books: Books.find().fetch()
  }
}, NewBooks);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Autoform depends heavily on Blaze, so, you could either use blaze autoform components in react (see [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/best-way-to-import-blaze-templates-into-react/20288)), or you can use a different library for this. I used this in a recent project: [github.com/nicolaslopezj/simple-react-form](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/simple-react-form). It's powerful, but much more 'hands-on' than the magical Autoform (you have to write your own form and field components).

Answer (score 4):

The npm package [Uniforms](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms) worked super easy with Bootstrap.

*Addition to ./imports/client/NewBooks.js*

```
import AutoForm from 'uniforms-unstyled/AutoForm';
...
<AutoForm
  schema={Books._collection.simpleSchema()}
  onSubmit={doc => console.log(doc)}
/>
```

Comment: Hi! In my case I had my model named **devices** loaded through **createContainer** and **Meteor.subscribe** so adding the **model** prop like this **model={device}** converted the form with populated data from the model!

`<AutoForm
        schema={Devices._collection.simpleSchema()}
        onSubmit={doc => console.log(doc)}
        model={device}
      />`

Comment: Uniforms looks promising!